# Why is the config.webServer exiting early?

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, playwright

I'm running E2E tests during GitHub Actions but have been usuccessful so far. When I run `npx playwright test e2e`, it works as intended.

```js
// playwright.config.js

import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
    webServer: {
        command: 'npm run start:staging --silent',
        url: 'http://localhost:3001', 
        timeout: 180 * 1000, 
        reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    },
      use: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3001/',
      },
    globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
    use: {
        // Use the saved storage state for all tests
        storageState: 'storageState.json',
    },
    // Other configurations...
});
```

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Run Playwright Tests on PR
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 5
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Install Node.js
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: '14'

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: npm install --silent

  - name: Install Playwright
    run: npx playwright install --with-deps

  - name: Determine PR base branch
    id: pr_base_branch
    run: echo "PR_BASE_BRANCH=$(jq -r '.pull_request.base.ref' $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: Run Playwright tests
    run: |
      if [[ "${{ env.PR_BASE_BRANCH }}" != "main" ]]; then
        npx playwright test e2e
      else
        echo "Skipping tests as the PR base branch is 'main'"
      fi

  - name: Set status checks
    if: ${{ always() }}
    run: |
      if [[ "${{ env.PR_BASE_BRANCH }}" != "main" ]]; then
        npx github-status failure -m "Playwright Tests failed"
      fi
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Error within GHA:

```
 Run if [[ "staging" != "main" ]]; then
 playwright.config.js executed
 [WebServer] One of your dependencies, etc. (non important 
 warning about babel plugins..


 Error: Timed out waiting [18]. 
 (<pathname>/job/19504604342#step:7:19)0000ms 
  from config.webServer.

 Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

It fails on the `Run Playwright tests` portion.

I've tried various approaches, but I've been unable to run Playwright tests in a GitHub Actions workflow.